# Fabric composer on Windows?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Is fabric-composer supported on Windows?
https://fabric-composer.github.io/tasks/prerequisites.html

How can I get an invitation to the Slack channel?
https://fabric-composer.github.io/support/index.html

Comment: There is an open issues for this, which is currently under investigation: https://github.com/fabric-composer/fabric-composer/issues/65

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for taking a look at fabric-composer.

All the technology that is being used is cross-platform (Node.js, npm, git and Hyperledger, Docker etc.) so have availability on Windows. The overall development experience wasn't as smooth for some of the tools as on say Ubuntu. For purely pragmatic reasons, therefore, it wasn't included at this time.

There is a git issue opened for including Windows. (https://github.com/fabric-composer/fabric-composer/issues/65)

Slack is a tool that is being looked at for building a community of contributors for fabric-composer. Please contact info@fabric-composer.org if there is an interest in being a contributor.

UPDATE on Windows Support
Please review the latest updates in the git issue mentioned above, I have been able to make good progress on this. Whilst support is not officially possible yet, I've been able to run the basic 'Hello World' application.

Comment: I actually followed the tutorial for hyperledger build a network and successfully setup hyperledger fabric on windows. Right now trying to setup the composer. But it has paths /etc/hyperledger etc which gives error.

Comment: I am able to run it on windows through Hyper-V hosted Ubuntu. I had done almost all the things on windows native docker but it was giving error at one point i can share with you if you will like to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

First step mentioned in Quickstart failed on Windows. Looks like we will need to wait till support for Windows is provided...

```
D:\fabric-composer>npm install -g composer-cli
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /composer-cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.1
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "composer-cli"
npm ERR! node v5.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! path C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\node-uuid-39ce4b7a
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\node-uuid-39ce4b7a' -> 'C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\composer-cli\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\node_modules\request\node_modules\node-uuid'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\fabric-composer\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: I managed to succesfully install composer recently. Seems like fsevents is now made optional. I haven't testran anything yet or tried to launch a fabric. Just installed on win10.

Answer (score -1):

hyperledger composer setup is not officially supported by windows .

You can try doing a setup on hosting a Ubuntu OS on a vmware .

setup is easy doing that .