# fabric composer on Windows machine

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I tried setting up playground using
https://fabric-composer.github.io/tutorials/getting-started-playground.html
I followed the docker steps everything started OK, was able to access Fabric Composer Playground by clicking on this link: http://localhost:8080

But now what??? I tried to upload a sample model file but it shows error.

How do I try this out. Do I have install Ubuntu on my windows machine to really be able to try out fabric composer?? Pleas help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fabric composer on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009850/fabric-composer-on-windows)

Comment: This is a duplicate. Short answer is yes, you need to run in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and run the fabric composer locally on linux only. For that you can use VMWare and install ubuntu on it.
And then follow the installation steps [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html).

If you don't want to do so, then alternatively you can use the [online composer playground](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiMsL7jnOLYAhUERo8KHcMYAgcQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcomposer-playground.mybluemix.net%2F&usg=AOvVaw2kZVVXOhitHEDEtlh-NzK0) and can export(download) your `.bna` file whenever you want.

Hope this helps you!